# UWP apps updates, WSUS or Windows Store?

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-server

So I'm upgrading a clients system to Windows 10. I want as little UWP app bloat as possible, so I'm using a PS script to remove all but the none essentials.

My question is, where does the UWP apps get their updates from? The Windows Store app or WSUS? I want to remove the Windows Store app if possible. But I also want the apps I leave to be updated.

Thankful for any input on this!

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft Store app manages the updates of the UWP apps.

**>>But I also want the apps I leave to be updated.**

Sideloaded apps could be updated without the Microsoft Store app. So you could check if the apps you want are sideloaded apps. If they are, then you could update them manually.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The ones I really want is the basics ones, like calculator and groove. I haven't sideloaded any, but you men's that some of the default once might be?

Comment: @Sec99 No, the default apps like calculator and groove are also UWP apps that you could find them in the Microsoft Store App.

Comment: That's what i though! Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear it could help you. Having a nice day!